# Secure way to create relative java.io.File

Tags: java, file, security

How do I create a `java.io.File` instance relative to a parent folder in a secure way, i.e. preventing a malicious attacker from breaking out of the parent folder.

Example:

```
  String path = request.getParameter( "path" );
  File file = new File( folder, path );
```

this is unsecure since the attacker might send me a `../../../etc/passwd` as `path`.

How do I "clean" such a path?

Comment: this kind of security is done by file permissions, why you need it in java?

Comment: Is it enough to keep the _black folder list_ and ensure that the path not in the list?

Comment: Because some interesting files might have to be readable to the server but not to the applications running on it. Reading `/etc/passwd` isn't a security hole by itself - it doesn't damage anything but the information learned from it makes it easier to attack the system.

Comment: @Michael: Since everything outside of `folder` is on the black list and I have no control over the "outside", I see no way to create such a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading the other answers, I came up with this solution:

```
public static boolean isParent( File parent, File file ) {

    File f;
    try {
        parent = parent.getCanonicalFile();

        f = file.getCanonicalFile();
    } catch( IOException e ) {
        return false;
    }

    while( f != null ) {
        // equals() only works for paths that are normalized, hence the need for
        // getCanonicalFile() above. "a" isn't equal to "./a", for example.
        if( parent.equals( f ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        f = f.getParentFile();
    }

    return false;
}
```

So the usage would be:

```
File file = new File( folder, path );
if( ! isParent( folder, file ) ) {
    ... deny access ...
}
```

The code above probably isn't very fast but all other solutions have security concerns:

- I could remove `/../|^../|/..$` but that wouldn't work on Windows. For Windows, the pattern would become more complex and don't forget that Java accepts `/` as file separator on Windows (yes, `C:/Windows/` is valid and means the same as `C:\Windows\`)

  Also, the path `a/../b/c` is valid since it doesn't break the boundary, so just removing the relative movements isn't good enough.
- I could create two strings using `getCanonicalPath()` and make sure the `parent` path is a prefix of `file`. But then, I'd have to make sure the character after the parent path is a file separator (see above why `File.SEPARATOR` isn't enough).

Answer (score 2):

<s>One solution would be to disallow anything that starts with `/` or `..`. But</s> I guess the "secure/proper" way is to run your application with a (JVM) security manager enabled and disallow file access outside the predefined configuration. But enabling a security manager requires some work figuring out all the permissions you need to be able to run tour application.

OS file permissons are also important, obviously.

**Edit**

Added an example, as requested. Example is from a current project deployed in Tomcat:

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/mywebapp/-" {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "path/to/folder", "read"; // Anything else will be disallowed
    // Other required permissions
}
```

Comment: According to the javadoc, leading `/` in `path` are stripped. Also `doesnotexist/../../..` would break your scheme. A security manager sounds like a nice idea but I've yet to see one which was configured correctly.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing out the flaw with the paths. Security permissions is a pain to set up, but it would solve the problem.

Comment: How would I have to set up the security manager in this case? Note that `folder` is relative to the installation directory, so it's only known for sure at runtime.

Comment: Enabling and configuring a security manager depends on your application server. But usually it involves configuring the `java.policy` (or equivalent) file. I don't know what your installation directory is, but the code base settings in the policy files can handle relative urls, if that would solve the issue.

Comment: Can you please add an example to your answer?

Comment: Ok, I added an example. But I assume your issue is that `path/to/folder` is not known?

Comment: Yes, it's a work folder relative to whatever my application server wants me to write to. So I'd need an example how I can "update" the security manager at runtime - but I have a feeling that's not how it works :-)

Comment: I'm surprised to see `${catalina.base}` in the config file. Is that a feature of the standard security manager?

Comment: But the work folder is static once the app has started? Or at least a common parent folder is? Property expansion is possible with standard java policy: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html#PropertyExp

Comment: Yes, the folder doesn't change. But I only know the path once `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()` has been called. So it's quite far after the start of the application.

Comment: Can you describe how the folder is resolver? What is it based on?

Comment: In my example: `folder = new File( context.getRealPath( "images" ) )` where `context` is an instance of `ServletContext`

Answer (score 1):

```
    String path = "../../../etc/passwd";
    String pureFilename = (new File(path)).getName();
    File file = new File(folder, pureFilename);
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Can I preserve `etc` as well (the relative paths *might* contain sub folders)?

Comment: but you would lose the "abc" in new File("abc/def").getName()

Comment: You can get the path similarly via String purePath = (new File(path)).getParentFile().getCanonicalPath() and analyse the path according to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

```
boolean isChild(File parent, File child) throws IOException {
    String parentCanonicalPath = parent.getCanonicalPath();
    String childCanonicalPath = child.getCanonicalPath();
    return childCanonicalPath.startsWith(parentCanonicalPath);
}
```

Comment: That looks good until you try parent = `foo` and child `foobar` (i.e. the last common folder is different but starts with the same characters).